# How can I delete lines that I read from file line by line in PHP

Tags: php, file, file-io

I have a code here:

```
 $file = fopen('a.txt', 'r');
 while (!feof($file)){
     $word = trim(fgets($file));
         // calling a function on $word
 }
```

I want to delete the `$word` at the end of while. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to delete this from the file?  Or you just want a substring?

Comment: I want to delete $word from a file

Comment: @fahimeh: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Can you add an example in the question? (the intial file contents, and the expected output)?

Comment: I have a file (a.txt) that contains english words. In each line I have a word, I want to read each of them line by line and after sending each of them to a function, delete them one by one after the function

Comment: The way to use files: You write a new file containing the information that you want from the old file, in the format that you want. You close the old and new files. You decide what to do with the old file.